# Stop from entering a null value in apex inline edit

Tags: apex, visualforce, inlineeditsupport, outputfield, null

I have the following code

```
<apex:outputField value="{!pubAut.AcceptedDate__c}">  
    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" rendered="{!(pubAut.AcceptedDate__c!=NUll&&pubAut.SentDate__c!=Null)}"/>                      
</apex:outputField>
```

Is it possible to stop someone from entering a null value in the inline edit?

Comment: Validation rules maybe.....If had a value and is now null throw validation error or something like that. But this would not be unique to inline edit